# AWS Step Function replaces characters in JSON with replacement character U+FFFD �

Tags: json, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I am using a Step Function method that gets started using a JSON query that passes a AWS API Gateway call (that has an application/json body mapping template). 
All goes well, but sometimes a customer name (which is in the JSON) contains an non-standard character, for example the é, accented e. This subsequently gets replaced in the input JSON in StepFunction with a � symbol which is used to replace an unknown, unrecognized or unrepresentable character.

Any idea how to convince Step Functions to keep the original characters? I've checked the JSON that gets send to the API, it contains the é so on my side everything seems fine.

Perhaps I should replace it with '\u00E9' but then I should do this for other characters as well, an how do I know beforehand which characters to convert?

I checked the JSONString to be UTF-8 encoded:

```
CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
detector.setText(jsonO.toJSONString().getBytes());
System.out.println(detector.detect().getName());
```

And this is the http post that I have adjusted to send UTF-8:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "some_url");

    String json = "{\"dna_match\":BLADIEBLA,\"dna_match_info\":\"3rd COUSIN\"}";
    StringEntity entity = null;
    try {
        entity = new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");
        entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        //entity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

        String responseAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        client.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect2api.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect2api.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Still no effect...

Comment: You have verified that your character is encoded as two octets of utf-8 (`0xC3A9`) and not one octet of something latin (`0xE9`), yes?  My unscientific observations suggest that AWS systems that handle JSON seem to have a tendency to replace invalid (non-utf-8) octets with � rather than reject the request out of hand.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I quickly tried to generate a UTF8 String but that didn't work as well (i got questionmarks instead of the �) : String jsonOutf8 = "";
      try {
       jsonOutf8 = new String(jsonO.toJSONString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

Comment: I checked encoding with: CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
      detector.setText(jsonO.toJSONString().getBytes());
      System.out.println(detector.detect().getName());  // <- return the result, you can check by .getName() method     so that seems to be fine. Perhaps it needs another encoding, I will check.

Comment: I realized the HttpPost should also be informed about the correct encoding. I added some UTF-8 settings but no effect, see original comment.